# Cannot tab to select dropdown menus in Bootstrap Navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility

So I'm having a problem where for some reason you can't select the dropdowns from my Bootstrap navbar using the tab key? I'm concerned that this means people using screen-readers and the such  won't be able to navigate the website. It seems to work on other bootstrap sites so I don't know what's wrong.

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>yiskah @ spooky camp</title>
  <!-- CSS -->
  <link href="../css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/navbar-static-top.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/bootstrap-accessibility.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#content" class="sr-only sr-only-focusable">Skip to main content</a>
  <!-- Static navbar -->
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
     <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">brand</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
              <li><a href="../sorry">Robo-Apologizer</a></li>
                <li><a href="../photoshop">Photoshop Idea Generator</a></li>
                <li><a href="../diviii">Div III Generator</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Written Work<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="../lexrep">Lexical Replacement</a></li>
                <li><a href="../mannequin">Mannequin Allies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">@Elsewhere <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
            <li><a>(links to social profiles)</a></li>
            <li><a>(one of my social links is here)</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li class="dropdown-header">Contact</li>
            <li><a>(one of my emails goes here)</a></li>
            <li><a>(I put another email here)</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

I haven't modified any of the default bootstrap code. I have this problem on other sites I've tried to implement the navbar on. But it works fine on the examples on the bootstrap website?

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you added jquery and bootstrapjs file ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the href attribute on all the dropdown toggle anchors.
See [**this bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/UW3Wet166j) for the fixed version.

This:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Needs to be this:

```
 <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Or this:

```
 <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
```

Or this:

```
 <a tabindex="0" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
```